# Define rules for multiple user login in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

In my project i have 2 users `Organiser` and `User` with 2 different tables.

I want to define rules for `Event` table for both users. For example if `Organiser` is logged in which i can see as `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` and if `User` is logged in which i can see as `Yii::$app->users->isGuest` and i want to define separate rules for both users.

if `Organiser` logged in than only he can view that entire section and not `user` and same if `user` is logged in than he can only `create` the list of users.

If any visitor clicks on `Create an Event` than they should redirect to `Organiser Login` or if they click on `Create user` than they should redirect to `User Login`.
I have defined the rules like below but when it always redirect to `Organiser Login` and not the `user login`.

```
public function behaviors()
{

    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['index', 'view','create','update','delete'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index','view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['create','update','delete'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => false,
                    'verbs' => ['POST']
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

How can i define the rules based on which user is logged in???

Comment: I suggest yoy an evaluation of RBAC and AuthManager.  You should assign role to the User or Organiser and then assign permissione based on this role..

Answer (score 1):

I agree with scaisEdge that using rbac is a much better solution but if you really want to define a rule based on a user name it is possible. If you wanted user with username "testuser" to be the only one to access the "testPage" action of your controller, you could add something like the following to the rules array:

```
[
    'actions' => ['test-page'],
    'allow' => true,
    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action)
    {
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
            return false;

        return (Yii::$app->user->identity->username == 'testuser');
    }
],
```

Comment: no thats not it. I am letting 2 user to log in my project and i want them not to access certain models.

Comment: It's the same solution, just return false for them instead of true.